# Spring Boot startup issue with Spring Boot JPA Starter

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm getting this peculiar error when trying to start up my spring boot project with `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`. What is weird is that my application would start before I added a couple repositories and services but I can't seem to narrow down why spring cannot initialize a repository that was working before the additions.

Here is the related errors:

```
11:38:42.313 INFO  org.hibernate.Version.logVersion() @37 [localhost-startStop-1] - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.11.Final}
11:38:42.316 INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.<clinit>() @213 [localhost-startStop-1] - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found 
11:38:42.319 INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.buildBytecodeProvider() @317 [localhost-startStop-1] - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
11:38:42.430 INFO  org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version.<clinit>() @66 [localhost-startStop-1] - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
11:38:43.165 INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.<init>() @156 [localhost-startStop-1] - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
11:38:43.583 ERROR org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup() @63 [localhost-startStop-1] - Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'emailAuthenticationFilter' defined in class path resource [gg/leet/security/WebSecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [gg.leet.security.EmailAuthenticationFilter]: Factory method 'emailAuthenticationFilter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationManager' defined in class path resource [gg/leet/security/WebSecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager]: Factory method 'authenticationManager' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'emailAuthenticationProvider': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl' defined in file [/Users/andrew/Programs/leet-tournaments/backend/build/classes/main/gg/leet/service/UserServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#76212c93' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#76212c93': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
11:38:43.617 WARN  org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh() @550 [restartedMain] - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
11:38:43.631 ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure() @839 [restartedMain] - Application startup failed
```

The most interesting being the line:

> 11:38:43.583 ERROR org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup() @63 [localhost-startStop-1] - Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'emailAuthenticationFilter' defined in class path resource [gg/leet/security/WebSecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [gg.leet.security.EmailAuthenticationFilter]: Factory method 'emailAuthenticationFilter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationManager' defined in class path resource [gg/leet/security/WebSecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager]: Factory method 'authenticationManager' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'emailAuthenticationProvider': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl' defined in file [/Users/andrew/Programs/leet-tournaments/backend/build/classes/main/gg/leet/service/UserServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#76212c93' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#76212c93': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory

So the offending class that's in parameter 0 of `userServiceImpl` which is the `userRepository`.

This is what my UserRepository looks like:

```
package gg.leet.repository;

import gg.leet.model.User;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);
    @Query("select u from User u where u.id = ?1")
    Optional<User> findOneById(Long id);
    User save(User user);
    Optional<User> findOneByUsername(String username);
    List<User> findByEmailContaining(String search);
    List<User> findByFirstNameContaining(String search);
    List<User> findByLastNameContaining(String search);
    List<User> findByUsernameContaining(String search);
    @Query("select u from User u where u.username like ?1 or u.firstName like ?1 or u.lastName like ?1")
    Page<User> findByUsernameOrLastNameOrFirstNameContaining(String search, Pageable pageable);
}
```

UserService implementation:

```
package gg.leet.service;

import gg.leet.model.User;
import gg.leet.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.*;

/**
 * Implementation of the UserService over the mysql repository
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<User> getByUsername(String username) {
        return this.userRepository.findOneByUsername(username);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<User> getByEmail(String email) { return this.userRepository.findByEmail(email); }

    @Override
    public Optional<User> getById(Long id) {
        return this.userRepository.findOneById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public User save(User user) {
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public Page<User> findByContaining(String search, Pageable pageable) {
        return this.userRepository.findByUsernameOrLastNameOrFirstNameContaining(search, pageable);
    }
}
```

Nothing too fancy but I don't understand why we cannot instantiate a the bean for the authentication filter. The error is somewhat generic so I don't know where I should be looking. I tried to manually initialize the `entityManagerFactory` bean within a configuration class and reference it in the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation to no avail. Any advice on where I should also look to fix this issue?

----- EDIT 1 -----

Here is my datasource configuration, fairly minimal but has worked in the past:

```
spring:
  profiles: default
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/leettournaments?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC
    username: root
    password:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop


spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    max-active: 25
    max-idle: 10
  jpa:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

------ EDIT 2 ------

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Configuration
@EnableRedisHttpSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds=Integer.MAX_VALUE, redisFlushMode=RedisFlushMode.IMMEDIATE)
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig.class);

    @Value("${gg.leet.debug}")
    private boolean debug;

    /**
     * Establishes role hierarchy for user roles.
     * @return the RoleHierarchy
     */
    @Bean
    public RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy() {
        RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
        roleHierarchy.setHierarchy(
                "ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN > ROLE_LOCATION_ADMIN " +
                        "ROLE_LOCATION_ADMIN > ROLE_REGULAR_USER ");
        return roleHierarchy;
    }

    @Bean
    public RoleHierarchyVoter roleVoter() {
        return new RoleHierarchyVoter(roleHierarchy());
    }


    @Bean
    HeaderHttpSessionStrategy sessionStrategy() {
        return new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy();
    }


    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider emailAuthenticationProvider() {
        return new EmailAuthenticationProvider();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(
                emailAuthenticationProvider()
        ));
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccess authenticationSuccess() {
        return new AuthenticationSuccess();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationFailure authenticationFailure() {
        return new AuthenticationFailure();
    }

    @Bean
    public EmailAuthenticationFilter emailAuthenticationFilter() {
        EmailAuthenticationFilter filter = new EmailAuthenticationFilter(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login-process", "POST"));
        applyFilterAuthRules(filter);
        return filter;
    }

    private void applyFilterAuthRules(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter) {
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(authenticationSuccess());
        filter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailure());
        filter.setAllowSessionCreation(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/", "/**/*.css", "/**/*.js", "/index.html", "/ws/**", "/assets/**/*");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        if(debug) {
            LOGGER.warn("Allowing preflight options requests to all");
            // For the pre-flight request for options
            http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
                    .permitAll();
            // Disable csrf on debug dev
            LOGGER.warn("Allowing no CSRF protection");
            http
                    .csrf()
                    .disable();
        } else {
            http
                    .csrf()
                    .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
        }

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers( "/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler((new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler(HttpStatus.OK)))
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(emailAuthenticationFilter(), FilterSecurityInterceptor.class);



        http.requestCache().requestCache(new NullRequestCache());
        http.headers().cacheControl();
        http.headers().httpStrictTransportSecurity().disable();
        // .headers().contentSecurityPolicy(
        // .and().antMatcher("/bingo/card").;
    }

    @Bean
    protected BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

------ EDIT 3 ------

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.3.RELEASE'
        // classpath 'org.springframework:springloaded:1.2.6.RELEASE'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

idea {
    module {
        inheritOutputDirs = false
        outputDir = file("$buildDir/classes/main/")
    }
}

jar {
    baseName = 'leet-tournaments'
    version = '0.1.0'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

configurations {
    dev
    all*.exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}

dependencies {

    // Spring Boot Starter Framework
    compile(
            [group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '1.4.3.RELEASE'],
            [group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-log4j2', version: '1.2.0.RELEASE'],
            [group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security', version: '1.4.3.RELEASE'],
            [group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '1.3.2.RELEASE'],
            [group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-websocket', version: '1.0.0.RELEASE'],
            [group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-redis', version: '1.4.3.RELEASE'],
            [group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-devtools', version: '1.4.3.RELEASE'],
            [group: 'org.springframework.session', name: 'spring-session', version: '1.3.0.RELEASE'],
            [group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-messaging', version: '4.3.6.RELEASE'],
    )

    compile(
            [group: 'javax.mail', name: 'mail', version: '1.4.7'],
            [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.8.5'],
            [group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.35'],
            [group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.16.12'],
            [group: 'com.goebl', name: 'david-webb', version: '1.3.0'],
            [group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk', version: '1.11.77'],
            [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-hibernate5', version: '2.8.8'],
            [group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '22.0-rc1'],
    )

    compile(
            [group: 'io.netty',                 name: 'netty-all',              version: '4.1.7.Final'],
            [group: 'io.projectreactor',        name: 'reactor-core',           version: '2.0.7.RELEASE'],
            [group: 'io.projectreactor',        name: 'reactor-net',            version: '2.0.7.RELEASE'],
            [group: 'io.projectreactor.spring', name: 'reactor-spring-core',    version: '2.0.7.RELEASE'],
            [group: 'io.projectreactor.spring', name: 'reactor-spring-context', version: '2.0.7.RELEASE'],
    )

    // testing
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('junit:junit')
}

// gradle wrapper
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '3.0'
}

// run spring boot app
bootRun {
    addResources = true
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath + configurations.dev
}
```

Main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan
public class LeetTournaments {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(LeetTournaments.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LeetTournaments.class, args);
        // LeetTournaments.initDB();
    }

    static void initDB() {
        Webb webb = Webb.create();
        webb.get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/init").asString();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your datasource configurations

Comment: Spring can't fire up Hibernate for some reason, most likely there is a problem with your Hibernate configuration or your Spring JPA configuration.

Comment: I added the datasource configuration, this configuration has worked in the past. Where should I look to further configure Spring JPA?

Comment: @AndrewD, could you please post the implementation of the `gg.leet.security.WebSecurityConfig` class?

Comment: @SergeyBrunov I added the relevant class - thanks for taking a look at this for me.

Comment: @AndrewD, thank you for posting! Could you please also post the application class (the class that contains the `main` method) and related configuration classes (the classes annotated with the `@Configuration` annotation)?

Comment: @AndrewD, could you please the content of the `pom.xml` file as well?

Comment: @SergeyBrunov I added the gradle file I'm using to build and the websecurity config class. All my other config classes are for websockets and redis. Added main running class.

Comment: I know there are some redundant annotations there but those have worked in the past as well

Answer (score 0):

Please note the text marked with the bold font:

> Spring Data repositories usually extend from the `Repository` or `CrudRepository` interfaces. If you are using auto-configuration, repositories **will be searched from the package containing your main configuration class** (the one annotated with `@EnableAutoConfiguration` or `@SpringBootApplication`) down.
>
> — [Spring Boot Reference Guide, 29.3.2 Spring Data JPA Repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation).

Actually, I think that this is the solution to the problem (the text marked with the bold font):

> By default, Spring Boot will enable JPA repository support and look in the package (and its subpackages) where `@SpringBootApplication` is located. **If your configuration has JPA repository interface definitions located in a package not visible, you can point out alternate packages using `@EnableJpaRepositories` and its type-safe `basePackageClasses=MyRepository.class` parameter**.
>
> — [Getting Started · Accessing Data with JPA](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/).

All in all, consider updating the implementation of the `LeetTournaments` class as follows:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = UserRepository.class)
public class LeetTournaments {
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So after meticulous inspection, I found that one of my models had a conflicting key and this was the error I received. I appreciate all the time - I spent a few days tracking this one down. Wish there was more insight into the ORM even with the debug flag.

Comment: @AndrewD, this is good news. I think you should share the solution as a separate answer and mark it as the accepted answer.